# Database fields names for custom fields in CiviCRM

Tags: sql, database, field, civicrm

I created new contact type 'client', and created custom fields for client type like 'Ethnicity'.
I can now add records.
I need to create reports, for example the total number of clients with a certain Ethnicity.
The question is how can I know the database table and fields names?
I looked in wp-content->civicrm->civicrm->sql but found the basic tables only.

Comment: There is no _Fields_ in databases.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new set/group of fields there will be a new entry in the civicrm_custom_group table. The fields themselves are in civicrm_custom_field table.

The data for the fields is stored in civicrm_value__ so eg civicrm_value_client_fields_12

you may get better responses in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: Thanks for your response! I found